# I can't import node_modules from typescript in node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have one problem. I'm trying to import node_modules in typescript but I'm getting an error

`"[ts] Cannot find module 'path'."`

This is my code :

```
import path from 'path';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to install @types/node (you may want to add `--save-dev` or `--save`).

```
$ npm install @types/node
```

Then, in your code,

```
import * as path from 'path';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`import * as path from 'path';`

Comment: I'm getting same problem  error TS2307: Cannot find module 'path'.

Comment: Update your question with your tsconfig file please.